# Should it be different or differently?

Tags: grammar

> the exchange between the teacher and the student promotes learning **far different** from that which results as the student listens but does not participate.

I think: it should be "differently", since "learning" is just an abstract concept. To make it concrete so an adjective can be added to modify it, it should be "a learning". And since "different" indicate there are difference types of learning, "a learning", one of its kind, is more appropriate...

Comment: Definitely "different."

Comment: **Differently than ...** vs **Different from**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Everything preceding the word **"different"** in your example sentence is irrelevant.*

### Differently than

and

### Different from

You cannot say

> My father looks different than me

just like you cannot say

> My father looks differently from me.

Comment: That's sort of true, except you could say, "My father looks differently than I." And you cannot reduce this to a rule of "differently than vs. different from," as syntactical circumstances — not the word immediately following — determine whether the word is "differently" or "different." For example, http://www.grammar.com/different-from-vs-different-than/

Comment: Yes, but then *differently* would be describing *looks*, making it an adverb.  `My father looks differently than I` would mean that my father actually **looks** (with his eyes 0¿O) differently.

Comment: I just but a question: how can you say without the sentence looking awkward: "it's no different for men than it is for women."

Answer (score 1):

You'd use "differently" if "learning" was the verb "learn" in continuous form (-ing). However here it's quite clearly a noun describing the process, so "different" is an adjective - adverb wouldn't work here.

Comment: Differently can modify promote.........

Comment: Sure, but then it wouldn't make sense? promote differently?

Comment: Like in a different way